# $(this).... returns Window

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I cannot use $(this) within this code:

```
if ($('a:contains("Abb")').length > 0) { 
    $(this).addClass('hello'); 
}
```

This is what the browser returns:

[image]

I would like to add a class to an `<a>` tag if it contains the content "Abb". How can I do this?

Comment: That depends on where the code is written. Simply use `$('a:contains("Abb")').addClass('hello');`

Comment: why `this` would return something else than `Window` ?

Comment: Refer this link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check the length. Just use the add class.

```
$('a:contains("Abb")').addClass('hello');
```

This will add class `hello` to all the `<a>` which contains `Abb`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not in a function (a if/else statement doesn't create a scope), so **`this` refers to something out of the scope of the code you provided**. If there's no function wrapping it, **it refers to the window, in a web context**.

So in this context, you can't use `this` here, and you won't need it.

```
if ($('a:contains("Abb")').length > 0) { 
    $('a:contains("Abb")').addClass('hello'); 
}
```

Some doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a:contains("Abb")').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('hello');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure `$.each()` is useful here.